Divisor for a Riemann Surface
My question concerns the divisor of a Riemann surface.  My background is more physics than algebraic geometry, but my understanding is that to compute maps from the Riemann surface to it's Jacobian variety require a divisor, which itself must be a meromorphic function defined on a Riemann surface.  The divisor itself is a sum of zeros and poles of this meromorphic function with the multiplicities taken into account.
My question concerns how one would choose a divisor on a Riemann surface if I wanted to compute a map from the Riemann surface to it's Jacobian variety?
For example, let's I have the function
$f = y^{2} - (x^{2}-1)(x^{2}-4)(x^{2}-9)(x-4)$.  The specific function does not matter, I just want to be able to calculate an appropriate divisor for a Riemann surface given by a polynomial in $x$ and $y$.
This would be a $g=3$ Riemann surface if we set $f(x,y)=0$, and it is in Weierstrass form, so we have some extra information about the branch points of the surface to my understanding.
Would someone be able to show and explain how one could go about choosing and calculating an appropriate divisor for this Riemann surface, as the papers I have read mainly discuss the outline, but I feel I am still missing something?  I assume one would have to first define a local set of coordinates on the Riemann surface, but I don't really understand how to do that quite yet.  Additionally if anyone is willing to recommend references afterward from which I could improve my understanding in algebraic geometry, especially if they deal with calculations, I would appreciate that very much.  Thank you.

What kind of map $S\rightarrow J$ of a Riemann surface $S$ to its Jacobian $J$ do you want to contruct? From an algebraic point of view $J$ is an abelian group given explicitely by
$
J=\mathrm{Div}_0(S)/\mathrm{Prin}(S),
$
where $\mathrm{Div}_0(S)$ is the group of all divisors of degree $0$ on $S$ and $\mathrm{Prin}(S)$ is the subgroup of all divisors of meromorphic functions on $S$. Hence fixing an arbitrary point $P\in S$ ("base point") one can define a map
$
S\rightarrow J, Q\mapsto (Q-P)+\mathrm{Prin}(S).
$

I was intending to construct the Abel-Jacobi map from the Riemann surface to it's Jacobian variety.  Would you be able to provide an example based on this information?

The map provided in my post is "the" Abel-Jacobi map taking a purely algebraic point of view. (The dependence on the base point $P$ is only of minor importance.) Of course in this formulation it is neither clear that $J$ is an algebraic variety nor does the structure of $S$ as a Riemann surface show up.
